# Panel data dynamic model: transitory and permanent effect

Tags: regression, econometrics, panel-data

I want to ask about panel data dynamic model. For my thesis I have Gini as the dependent variable and trade as the independent variable and some other control variables such as education and corruption index. I'm using within estimator for 98 countries. I want to see the impact of trade openness on Gini.

$Y_{it} = B *Trade_{it} + B_1 Educ_{it} + B_2 CorrInd_{it} + \epsilon_{it}$

However, would it be possible to see if there's transitory or permanent effect of trade openness on Gini? I understand that I have to use lagged variables of Gini and Trade as well but do you think I also must put lagged for the control variables?